# Way to extract unique NSDates from NSArray using NSPredicate?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an NSArray of NewsArticle objects:

```
@interface NewsArticle : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *dateTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *content;

@end
```

And I want to create an `NSArray` of the unique dates (ignoring time) stored within each `article.dateTime` - I know I can do this the long way around by enumerating the array and doing the checking myself, but I'm hoping for a simpler solution.

I'm from a C# background and I know in C# I could do this with a simple `LINQ` statement - it would seem that `NSPredicate` might offer this functionality, but I can't work out how, or find any suitable examples online.

Comment: [Key Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) can help you with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSPredicate` is designed for filtering a collection of objects, but you want to extract a property from each member of the collection.

You can (as CAMOBAP said in his comment) use key-value coding (KVC) to get an array of all the `dateTime` values.  Then you can use an `NSSet` to eliminate the duplicates:

```
NSArray *allDateTimes = [articles valueForKey:@"dateTime"];
NSSet *uniqueDateTimes = [NSSet setWithArray:allDateTimes];
```

You can even do it all in one KVC message, using the somewhat esoteric `@distinctUnionOfObjects` key:

```
NSArray *uniqueDateTimes = [articles valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.dateTime"];
```

Note that this second example uses `valueForKeyPath:`, not `valueForKey:`.

You can learn more (oh so much more!) by reading the [*Key-Value Coding Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).

Comment: This is totally accurate, but the OP asked to ignore time, so don't you need to use some mechanism to strip off the time before doing the distinct operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `NSPredicate`, as already mentioned. Here is an alternative solution:

```
    NSMutableOrderedSet dailySet = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init]; //Or NSMutableSet if the order isn't important
    NSCalendar calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    for (NSDate *date in [articles valueForKey:@"dateTime"]) {

        if ([date isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
            [dailySet addObject:date]; //or don't add it
            continue;
        }

        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date];
        [dailySet addObject:[calendar dateFromComponents:components]];
    }
```